# Get creation-time of image or video in windows with php

Tags: php, windows, filetime

I have a bunch of image- and video-files and want to sort them by creation-date in Windows. In Windows-Explorer, I see a colum "date" which shows the correct date, all my files for testing are from 2019. But using php, it seems I'm not able to get this date: With filemtime, filectime or fileatime, I only get dates from August 2021.

Where is Windows getting the correct date from and how can I get it, too, in php?

Comment: _"Where is Windows getting the correct date from"_ - from the meta data embedded in the files themselves. (If you have a directory with many files, and Windows does not have this information "cached" yet - then you can often see the values appearing one by one with a bit of delay, because reading the actual files and parsing out the relevant information, takes a lot more time than just reading stuff like creation or modified date, which are provided by the file system itself.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to get this information out of windows, perhaps from a command on the cmd-line? It wouldn't matter if it takes some time to get this information, would prevent me from "reinventing the wheel" by parsing the different file-types.